# Bind boolean to class

Tags: css, knockout.js

I have a list of items and I want to highlight the "selected" one (this is linked to another interface, so using pure CSS will not work).  I'm guessing I could do this:

```
    <!-- ko if: isSelected -->
       <span class="selected">
    <!-- ko endif -->
       <span class="myItem">content goes here</span>
    <!-- ko if: isSelected -->
       </span>
    <!-- ko endif -->
```

and maybe even this:

```
    <span class="myItem<!-- ko if: isSelected --> selected<!-- ko endif -->">
       content goes here
     </span>
```

But I suspect there is a better way.  I have been unable to find it.

Comment: The syntax `data-bind="html: name, css: { clsSelected: isSelected}"` should work http://jsfiddle.net/RQBLV/. Please post your **exact** code and also the error messages from the browser console if there is any.

Comment: Yeah, I found my issue; I was overwriting the values elsewhere so they were all false.  Even though I found the same answer you posted, if you post as answer I'll give you the credit.

Comment: You should just undelete your answer, and rollback your question to its first version to not contain your attempts and solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html

```
<span class="myItem" data-bind="html: name, css: { selected: isSelected()"><span>
```

Works great!